# Copying Avatars over to new JIRA instance

Tags: migration, jira

I've created a new JIRA instance, copied over the avatars folder and re-indexed the instance several times. I have cleared my browser cache several times, restarted JIRA and also rebooted the server several times. I still don't see the avatars appear on the new instance. I've made sure all permissions are recursively the same as the original JIRA instance. No change.

I have asked this on Atlassian Answers as well, I thought I'd ask here to in case anyone happens to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only copy over avatars if you are importing the old database, as the database contains data that links the avatars to the users. So if you are creating a fresh instance of JIRA for a separate purpose, the users will have to manually re-add their avatars.